# Centering a specific sized div within a div

Tags: html, css, text-align

I have tried the normal techniques for horizontally centering a `div` within a `div`. I must still be doing something wrong. Check out the following jsFiddle and help me center the depiction of a tank under the "Inner Level" heading. For convenience I have added a border to all the div tags.

[jsFiddle Source](http://jsfiddle.net/czgoxafr/2/)

HTML:

```
<body>
  <a href="#">
    <div class="div-inline-block" style="text-align:left;width:150px;">
      <h2>TEST</h2>
      <p>A description</p>
    </div>

    <div class="div-inline-block"><p><b>Last Update:</b><br />???</p></div>
    <div class="div-inline-block"><p><b>Flow Rate:</b><br />??? gpm</p></div>
    <div class="div-inline-block"><p><b>Inner Level:</b><br />???</p><div class="tank-level-outer"><div class="tank-level-inner"></div></div></div>
    <div class="div-inline-block"><p><b>Outer Level:</b><br />???</p></div>
    <div class="div-inline-block"><p><b>Battery Voltage:</b><br />???</p></div>
    <div class="div-inline-block"><p><b>Rainfall:</b><br />???</p></div>
    <div class="div-inline-block" style="text-align:left;width:100%;"><p><b>Notifications:</b><br />???<br />???</p></div>
   </a>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
a{
    text-decoration:none;
}
div{
    border:1px solid red;
}
.div-inline-block {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left:15px;
    width: 100px;
}
.tank-level-outer {
    border:1px solid black;
    width:25px;
    height:32px;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.tank-level-inner {
    background-color:dodgerblue;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/czgoxafr/3/ ??

Comment: Post your code in your question please. Always.

Comment: Here [**CSS-Tricks - Centering: The complete guide**](http://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/)

Comment: The answers below will center the div, but now the inner div is top aligned instead of bottom aligned. I am guessing there is a conflict between using table, table-cell, and alignments. display:table-cell was the easiest way to align the inner div to the bottom

Comment: are you saying this fiddle is top alligned??? http://jsfiddle.net/czgoxafr/8/ please explain

Comment: Yes, the `div` with the blue background should be aligned to the bottom of the `div` with the black outline. As soon as you change the `display` property to anything other than `table-cell`, it aligns the inner `div` to the top of the outer `div`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/czgoxafr/17/ let me know if it is fine??

Comment: Yes, but it is artificially aligned by using the `top` property. I would like to have it be truly aligned to the bottom of the outer `div` because the size is going to change dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

add this

```
    .div-inline-block {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left:15px;
    width: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.tank-level-outer {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 25px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
}
.tank-level-inner {
    background-color:dodgerblue;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    margin-top:7px;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

**Updated Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/czgoxafr/22/

Comment: The blue inner `div` has completely filled the outer `div`. It should have a gap at the top of 7 px.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.tank-level-outer {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: An explanation of your solution would be helpful.

Comment: That centers the `div`, but now the inner `div` is top aligned instead of bottom aligned. I am guessing there is a conflict between using `table`, `table-cell`, and alignments. `display:table-cell` was the easiest way to align the inner div to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

change the css of div .tank-level-outer and add margin zero auto , remove display table-cell

```
.tank-level-outer {
border: 1px solid #000;
width: 25px;
height: 32px;
margin: 0px auto;
vertical-align: bottom;}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
.tank-level-outer {
   width:25px;
   height:32px;
   display:block; // not necessary since this class is applied to a div
   vertical-align:bottom;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
//css

.firstDiv{
padding:25% 25% 25% 25%
height:400px;
width:400px;
background-color:red;
}

.secondDiv{
height:200px;
width:200px;
background-color:pink;
}

//html

<div class="firstDiv">
<div class="secondDiv">
</div>
</div>
```